# Install MySQL client only on Mac for Google App Engine local machine Python

Tags: google-app-engine, mysql-python

I'd like to setup a dev environment with Google App Engine Python (dev_appserver.py) with MySQL on Mac.

I am able to do it if I also install MySQL server on the local computer. I'd like to use Docker instead to host the MySQL database server.

`pip install mysqlclient -t libs` throws `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found` which seems correct as there is mysql installed. What library or approach should I use?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly found error
You can try installing `pymysql` on Mac

and import it

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    handleError()
```